# Unable to update TextField object in qml from cpp code

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to set a text field object "fname" in my qml from my cpp code using the following

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(fname,"setText", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QString, "Sample Text"));
```

but i am getting the below error.Any ideas?

```
QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread.
```

Comment: Is it a multithreaded application? Possibly calling QML from other than main thread?

Comment: Where are you starting the timer ? Post more code.